# Error when export to Excel in SharePoint

Tags: excel, export

I get an error when choosing "Export to Excel" in SharePoint:

> Excel cannot complete this task with available resource. Choose less data or close other applications

What can the problem be?

Comment: How many records do you have in the list?

Comment: Not much  Records

Comment: http://uupload.ir/files/4sb1_screenshot_(166).png  http://uupload.ir/files/bkrt_screenshot_(167).png

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your computer is running out of memory and cannot complete the job. Reboot your computer, close any apps and programs that are not required, so you have the most memory available.  Then try again. If you run into the same error, you will need to run this job from a computer with more memory.

Comment: tanks for ansewr. but  my computer is oky . only this site  have problm for export to excel. what i do?

Comment: Well, the error message comes from your computer, not from the SharePoint site. If you're sure it's not your computer, but the SharePoint site, then please upload all the SharePoint error logs and the ULS files and the diagnostic logs and the server error logs and all other stuff for inspection. Just joking. But really, if you don't provide more information, how can you expect help?

Comment: but other list i can do export excel

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you have excel 86x. Your excel can only call so much memory (2gb if you have a 86x windows or 4gb if its 64x windows version off the top of my head) so while your computer may be fine, it is limited by your excel version.

[Edit] If you are running 64x version of excel on a x64 system and assuming you have enough physical memory then maybe your computer has limited virtual memory - check and see if over 4gb is available for it to use.

I am speaking from experience here as it has happened to me. Teylyn is right in saying its not server side.

Can I suggest making a blank list - adding 1 item and seeing if that can be exported to excel. If that doesn't work then maybe its to do with permissions.

Comment: photo of erroe when i export excel in Share Point list http://uupload.ir/files/4sb1_screenshot_(166).png   http://uupload.ir/files/bkrt_screenshot_(167).png

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offers several explanations as well as troubleshooting steps for this error here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2779852/how-to-troubleshoot-available-resources-errors-in-excel

I would start by monitoring my pc's memory usage when trying to export the file to excel. You can open the resource monitor and keep an eye on the memory usage when doing the export. If you are not running low on memory, then I would look at the version of excel that is installed. Try updating to the latest version if not already there. I would also test this from another PC with Excel installed and see if I had the same error. If so, Start looking at the contents of the list in SharePoint. Is there something that is not compatible?

Comment: my version excel 64 bit and my IE 64 but dont working